# Python Beautiful Soup Помогиту удалить "<tr></tr>"

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

**Вот сам код:**

```
  with open('index.html') as file:
     src = file.read()   
  soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
  tram_schedule = soup.find('div', class_='column working-days').find_all('tr')
  for tram in tram_schedule:
     print(tram)
```

Получаю вот это:

```
<tr></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">31</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">46</spam></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">00</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">15</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">30</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">45</spam></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">00</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">15</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">30</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">43</spam></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Помоните удалить эту первую строку `<tr></tr>`

Comment: откуда удалить?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, часть исходного файла с `'div', class_='column working-days'`

Comment: из tram_schedule. Эта первая строка <tr></tr> мешает дальнейшей обработки даных. Если  print(tram.text) - получается пустая трока., которая мне очень мешает. Может есть возможность цикл for tram in tram_schedule: засустить не с 0 а с 1 елемента.

Comment: `for tram in tram_schedule[1:]:`

Comment: <div class="column working-days">
<div class="title">days</div>
<table><tr></tr><tr><td>6</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">31</spam></td><td

Comment: Большое спасибо CrazyElf. Решение  for tram in tram_schedule[1:]: как временное пойдет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_code = """<tr></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">31</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">46</spam></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">00</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">15</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">30</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">45</spam></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">00</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">15</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">30</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">43</spam></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')
# tram_schedule = soup.find('div', class_='column working-days').find_all('tr')
for tram in filter(lambda x: x.find('td'), soup.find_all('tr')):
    print(tram)
```

#### UPD

> Совсем забыл. Вот так еще можно:

```py
for tram in soup.select('tr:has(td)'):
    print(tram)
# тоесть в Вашем случае
# for tram in soup.find('div', class_='column working-days').select('tr:has(td)'):
#     print(tram)
```

> Результат будет одинаковый

---

```html
<tr><td>6</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">31</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">46</spam></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">00</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">15</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">30</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">45</spam></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">00</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">15</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">30</spam></td><td class="default-td color-gray"><spam class="">43</spam></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: Спасибо и так работает. Под себя немножко переделал.      for tram in filter(lambda x: x.find('td'), soup.find('div', class_='column working-days').find_all('tr')):

Comment: @ruslan, я там немного ответ поправил

Comment: Большое Спасибо.  Этот вариант так же работает!!!! Круто!!!